# Displaying images or controls in Visual Studio source view

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vs-extensibility

I'm working on a number-crunching app with some fairly (from my POV) complex math. My first thought was,

> Gee, it'd be really nice to be able to take a screen shot in
>   Mathematica and include it as a comment in my C# source.

I see a `cdata` value when entering `///` alongside summary, remarks, and other options. Custom tags appear to also be supported (as there doesn't appear to be any validation happening).

In order of preference, I'd like to:

1. Link Mathematica code to my C# source, and have said code appear, in all its Greek-laden glory, as a comment above the method that calls it (or from which it was generated). Bonus points for actually embedding the Mathematica editor in VS!
2. Link to an image file containing a screenshot of the above, manually generated via Paint and the [snip tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/snipping-tool), and have VS display it.
3. Embed the image in a CDATA section, and have it automagically render inside of VS when viewing the code, inline with said code. Generating a base-85 (or whatever) encoded version of an image is trivial. The problem at this point is getting it to display.

Ways that this is possible:

1. Write an app that overlays an image on the screen and, via magic, keeps it aligned with the source view in VS. (This is ridiculous, but, hey, so is a language that requires you to denote variable names with a `$`, and yet has a full BNF grammar available to anyone who can Google. Oh, what a world...)
2. I got nothing.

Suggestions? Is it possible to extend VS so that an image, or control (where Mathematica could be hosted), can appear in the source view?

*(note: one of my favorite statements is "It's software. Anything is possible. Give me a 9-volt battery, a paper clip, pocket knife and a monkey hopped up on speed, and we'll make it happen." In this case, I mean within the realm of practicality.)*

Comment: how about using a VS plugin?

Comment: @Filip - sure, but how? It's not clear to me how to affect the source view via plugin.

Comment: seems one already exists, see answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this Visual Studio plug-in should solve most of your requirements:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/793d16d0-235a-439a-91df-4ce7c721df12

Comment: Looks interesting - very close to what I need.